# How to redirect subdomain to another router extracting as argument

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, robots.txt

I need to redirect all `robots.txt` to a specific root domain url.

Here is an example

```
https://example.com/robots.txt => https://example.com/robots_handler?domain=
https://sub1.example.com/robots.txt => https://example.com/robots_handler?domain=sub1
https://sub2.example.com/robots.txt => https://example.com/robots_handler?domain=sub2
```

I hope you got an idea.

It would be great if it could be possible without hardcoding domains.

How can I achieve the similar result using `htaccess` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(([a-z0-9-]+)\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^robots.txt$ /robots_handler?domain=%2 [L]
```

`RewriteCond` can be used to capture the subdomain then it can be passed as query string to robots_handler. `%1` is the backreference to the regex part `(([a-z0-9-]+)\.)` whereas `%2` is the backreference to the regex part `([a-z0-9-]+)`. If the request URI is `robots.txt`, rewrite the URL to `/robots_handler?domain=%2`.